# How can I test the MariaDB CONNECT Storage Engine with MongoDB - Does a connector exist?

Tags: mongodb, mariadb

According to a few articles I've read (e.g. [here](https://mariadb.com/blog/best-both-worlds) and [here](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/08/08/google_backs_mariadb/)), MariaDB supports connection, command and querying of external data sources using the CONNECT Storage Engine.

Specifically, I'd like to test with MongoDB. Is there a connector that I can download and documention specific to MongoDB? My Google searches so far have come up short.